# How can I make tkinter wait for a line of code to finish before continuing?

Tags: python, tkinter

so I am making a program on tkinter that gets a response from a server and depending on the answer, it will change the background color, to either green for success or red for error, the problem is that I realized that when running the code, the windows.after() method doesn't wait till is done to continue and when I do the request for the server, it have to do it three times to check if the response is correct, and it is suppossed to change the window background color each time, but it is only doing it one time. And not only the background color changing fails, also I want to change a label's text when it is doing the request,but it does it really quick and I'm not able to diferentiate the changes, so the question is: how can I
How can I make the program wait until one line finishes running to go to the next one and not everything happens at the same time and so fast?
Here is a piece of my code, I removed the request part because I'm trying to solve this problem first:

```
# import gpiozero
# import picamera
import json
import requests
import tkinter as tk

with open("config.json") as file:
    config = json.load(file)

ENDPOINT = config["ENDPOINT"]
USUARIO = config["USUARIO"]
ESTACION = config["ESTACION"]
TIEMPO_ESPERA = config["TIEMPO_ESPERA"]
PIN_RELE = config["PIN_RELE"]
PATH_SALIDA = ENDPOINT + "Salida.getTicket/" + ESTACION + "/" + USUARIO + "/"
barcode = ""

# RELAY = gpiozero.OutputDevice(PIN_RELE, active_high=True, initial_value=False)
# CAMERA = picamera.PiCamera()

def check_scan_barcode(event=None):
    info_label.config(text = "Wait...")
    barcode = barcode_entry.get()
    barcode_entry.delete(0, "end")
    for i in range(3):
        response = get_request(ENDPOINT + barcode)
        if response["data"] == "True":
            success()
            open_barrier()
        else:
            error()
    info_label.config(text = "Scan barcode")

def get_request(url):
    response = requests.get(url)
    response.raise_for_status()
    response = response.json()
    return response

def normal():
    window.configure(bg="white")
    info_label.configure(bg="white")

def success():
    window.configure(bg="green")
    info_label.configure(bg="green")
    window.after(1000, normal)
    
def error():
    window.configure(bg="red")
    info_label.configure(bg="red")
    window.after(1000, normal)

def open_barrier(barcode):
    # CAMERA.capture(f"/home/pi/Pictures{barcode}.jpg")
    # RELAY.on()
    # window.after(TIEMPO_ESPERA, RELAY.off)
    pass

window = tk.Tk()
    
# window.attributes('-fullscreen', True)

info_label = tk.Label(window, text= "Scan barcode.", font=("Arial", 40))
info_label.pack()
barcode_entry = tk.Entry(window, width=50)
barcode_entry.bind('<Return>', check_scan_barcode)
barcode_entry.pack(expand=True)
barcode_entry.focus()

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I don't see anything in the code you posted that actually attempts to make any kind of internet connection, so I can't understand the problem. Exactly where is the code supposed to "wait", and what does it mean that this line of code has "finished"? Please also try to write in clearer sentences and paragraphs. I have a hard time following your train of thought.

Comment: I justa added the rest of the code, I removed because I was trying to solve the background color problem first, and for the "finished" I mean that it makes the request and then changes the bg color to either red or green for a second, three times to check if the response was correct, but it only changes the color one time but executes it 3 times, also the label text change is to fast to see it, so I want to wait a little between each loop.

Comment: Technically, the `window.after()` call DID finish.  It set up a timer to call your `RELAY.off()` function after the time time interval.  You program will continue to run, and after the time interval the call will be done.  If you want the program to pause, use `time.sleep()` and call the function directly.   Although `time.sleep()` is not a good idea in an event-driven framework unless it's done in a separate thread.

Comment: But the bg color only changes one time after the 3 loops.

Comment: Try adding `window.update_idletasks()` after `info_label.configure(...`.